# CK-editor, autoset styles in dropdown with custom.css

Tags: ckeditor

I'm having trouble with CK4 and getting the styles for headers reflected in the styles-dropdown.

The .css should be shared of both back- and frontend and uses #page as css-id

Is there any way to tell the dropdown to parse headers with the #page-prefix.

I'm using

```
 CKEDITOR.config.bodyId = 'page';
```

and css

```
.cke_editable {
}

#page {
    /* works - editor area goes black..
    font-family:Arial;
    margin:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:#000;
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#fff;

}

#page h1 {
   /* works in editor-area, but not dropdown */
    font-family: Verdana;
    color:#999;
}

.cke_editable h2 {
  /* same as h1.. */
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#f00;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:#999;
}

h3 {
   /* work BOTH in editor and style shows in dropdown. */
    color:#0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achived a working solution by parsing the css e.g.

```
 #page h1 {...}
```

when attaching to CK like:

```
['config']['css'] = 'parseMyCss.php?theFile=style.css
```

and in parseMyCss (simplified):

```
$s = file_get_contents($theFile);
$s = str_replace('#page ','', $s);
header('content-type:text/css');
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're about to use [stylesheetparser](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles#Stylesheet_Parser_Plugin) plugin to parse additional selectors. This issue has already been answered here: [CKEditor - Stylesheet Parser - Valid Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224158/ckeditor-stylesheet-parser-valid-selectors/14225233#14225233)

It's not straightforward but I believe you'll manage to do this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CKEditor doesn't apply the bodyId and/or bodyClass to the styles combo: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7452

As you can see that bug was reported almost two years ago and it has been without activity from the developers most of that time.